# How to write a SQL Script to Insert/Update Data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update, sql-scripts

In SQL Server I have a temporary table called - `massupdate` and a main table called `retaildata`

The structure is as follows.

Table massupdate:

```
| retail_id     | Qty| 
| 1             | 1  | 
| 2             | 2  |
```

Table retaildata:

```
| retail_id     | Qty| 
| 1             | 1  | 
| 2             | 2  |
```

`retaildata` has more columns also but these 2 are same as temptable `massupdate`.

What basically should happen is that if `retail_id` in `massupdate` table is present in `retaildata` then update the `qty` in `retaildata` table with `qty` of `massupdate` table. If `retail_id` of `massupdate` doesn't exist in `retaildata`  table, then make an insert query for `retaildata` table. Basically, the business has given one Excel and I am feeding those data in `massupdate` table and then comparing with main table `retaildata`.

I have written a query like this but it's not correct:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT retail_id FROM retaildata WHERE retail_id in (select   retail_id from massupdate))

BEGIN

    UPDATE S SET s.Qty= C.Qty FROM retaildata S inner join massupdate C on S.retail_id=C.retail_id

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO retaildata (retail_id,Qty,Trigger_Suppress,Next_Ship_Date,Next_Ship_Qty,Last_Ship_Date,Last_Ship_Qty,Carrier_Text,Ship_Number,Work_Pack_Code,Supplier_Part_Number,Supplier_Inv_Qty,Ship_Comments,Last_Updt_User,Last_Updt_Date)

    SELECT     retail_id,Qty,'N',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'BATCH TRRIGER INSERT/UPDATE',Getdate() FROM massupdate END
```

Comment: postgres or sql-server?

Comment: SQL Server @Jens

Comment: You're describing a `MERGE`.

Comment: @larnu - Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of situations are usually handled by a merge statement. Something like this should get you started

```
create table #retaildata (retail_id int,Qty int,Trigger_Suppress nvarchar(max),Next_Ship_Date datetime,Next_Ship_Qty datetime,Last_Ship_Date datetime,Last_Ship_Qty datetime,Carrier_Text datetime,
                            Ship_Number int,Work_Pack_Code nvarchar(max),Supplier_Part_Number int,Supplier_Inv_Qty int, Ship_Comments nvarchar(max),Last_Updt_User nvarchar(max),Last_Updt_Date datetime);

create table #massupdate (retail_id int,Qty int);

insert #retaildata (retail_id, Qty, Trigger_Suppress, Last_Updt_User) values (1, 3, 'TEST', 'Previous insert');

insert #massupdate values (1, 5), (2, 1);

select * from #retaildata;

MERGE #retaildata as target
using
(select retail_id, Qty,'N' as Trigger_suppress,null as Next_Ship_date ,null as Next_Ship_Qty,null as Last_Ship_Date ,null as Last_Ship_Qty,null as Carrier_Text,null as Ship_Number,null as Work_Pack_Code,null as Supplier_Part_Number,
null as Supplier_Inv_Qty,null as Ship_Comments,'BATCH-TRRIGER INSERT/UPDATE' as Last_Updt_User,Getdate() as Last_Updt_Date FROM #massupdate) as source
on target.retail_id=source.retail_id
when matched then update set target.Qty=source.Qty
when not matched then insert (retail_id,Qty,Trigger_Suppress,Next_Ship_Date,Next_Ship_Qty,Last_Ship_Date,Last_Ship_Qty,Carrier_Text,Ship_Number,Work_Pack_Code,Supplier_Part_Number,Supplier_Inv_Qty,
       Ship_Comments,Last_Updt_User,Last_Updt_Date)
       values (retail_id,Qty,Trigger_Suppress,Next_Ship_Date,Next_Ship_Qty,Last_Ship_Date,Last_Ship_Qty,Carrier_Text,Ship_Number,Work_Pack_Code,Supplier_Part_Number,Supplier_Inv_Qty,
       Ship_Comments,Last_Updt_User,Last_Updt_Date);

select * from #retaildata;
drop table #massupdate, #retaildata;
```

Comment: Getting an error with this query- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: I'll create a stub of data so you have an example you can run bear with

Comment: Please see updated query which is a runnable example

Comment: I have also included your sample data to demonstrate the update and insert behaviour.

Comment: Thank yo so much for your help @Dwight

Comment: No problem @SumitDwivedi if you can mark my answer as accepted if it has solved your problem then I would appreciate that :)

Answer (score -1):

We have to always use MERGE statement whenever there is an Insert/Update logic involved.